# An unknown symbol looking like a red pin marker with "EMD" text shown on the screen

Tags: overlay, vivo

I have a Vivo Android phone. The screen is showing a red pin marker with "EMD" text in it.

[image]

<sup>(Click the image to see in full size)</sup>

What is this, and how to remove this?

Comment: check your app drawer and widgets for similar icon